# AngularJS/Mongoose: how to assign objects if you have the ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs, mongoose

I have a way that works, it just seems like a stupid way of doing things.

I have an `Invoice` object (`$resource`) that has a `client` value, which, because of the way Mongoose works, is assigned to an ID. But, I want to use the `client` values (e.g. `client.name`, `client.address`, etc.) in the invoice views in Angular. Here's the code I have, which takes `invoice.client` (an ID) and reassigns the whole `client` object:

```
Invoices.query(function(invoices) {
    angular.forEach(invoices, function(invoice){
        Clients.get({
            clientId: invoice.client
        }, function(client) {
            invoice.client = client;
        })
    });
    $scope.invoices = invoices;
});
```

This seems very redundant, because I already have all the clients loaded in `$scope.clients`, but I couldn't think of a way to use those instead, which would require far fewer database calls.

$scope.clients is a promise object, since it is populated like this:

```
Clients.query(function(clients) {
    $scope.clients = clients;
});
```

Comment: Paste an example of what `$scope.clients` looks like.

Comment: It's a promise, I guess. I'm a little confused about when it gets fulfilled. But once it's full it has an array of client objects, with properties like `name`, `phone`, `email`, etc.